# Typecast for qsort function pointer

Tags: c, casting, function-pointers, strcmp, qsort

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <assert.h>

    static int cmpstringp(const void *p1, const void *p2)
    {
       /* The actual arguments to this function are "pointers to
          pointers to char", but strcmp(3) arguments are "pointers
          to char", hence the following cast plus dereference */

        return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
    }

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int j;

        assert(argc > 1);

        qsort(&argv[1], argc - 1, sizeof(argv[1]), cmpstringp);

        for (j = 1; j < argc; j++)
            puts(argv[j]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
```

I'm confused with this part:

```
        return strcmp(* (char * const *) p1, * (char * const *) p2);
```

Why did they do this? Why did they NOT do this: `(const char**)` or `(const char * const*)`? Don't we get a pointer to a const char if we dereference once for `(const char**)`? Dereferencing the second one, don't we get a const pointer that points at a const char. Both of these seem to what `strcmp()` asks for: two pointers who point at const chars. What the man page seems to give us const pointers pointing at non-const things, which doesn't seem to be what `strcmp()`'s declaration is asking for. Even if legal, it doesn't seem like a good idea to give a function something that doesn't fit its parameters. Am I missing something?

Lastly, why does the following not generate at least an error warning:

```
    auto const char * const ptr3 = *(const char **) ptr1; //where ptr1 is    
    of the form int foo(const void * ptr).
```

Dereferencing `ptr1` once gives us a pointer to a const char, but is not itself const. However, `ptr3` is const. So why doesn't the compiler generate a warning? Am I missing something, or is there a reason it shouldn't be generating a warning?

Comment: Forget that `auto` is a keyword in C - or don't use it.  C++11 has defined a use for it, but in C99 it is noise.

Answer (score 2):

**Last question first:**

This is fine:

```
const void *ptr = ...;
const char * const ptr3 = *(const char **) ptr1;
^^^^^^^^^^^^ ~~~~~          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |                            |
     +----------------------------+
```

Here, I can simplify it with a typedef:

```
typedef const char * string;
const void *ptr = ...;
const string ptr3 = *(string *) ptr;
~~~~~ ^^^^^^          ^^^^^^
        |                |
        +----------------+
```

The `const` in the local variable (the one underlined with `~~~~~`) is not really necessary: it specifies that the *local variable* `ptr3` is `const`, not that the data it points to is const.

**Next question:** Why (or why not) not `*(const char * const *) ptr1` ?

Well, the type of `*(const char * const *) ptr1` is `const char * const`, or `const string` if you are using the typedef.  But it's only used as an rvalue.  There is no difference between a const and non-const rvalue.  For example, look at the following code:

```
void *ptr = ...;
int x = *(const int *) ptr;
int y = *(int *) ptr;
```

Obviously, `x` and `y` get the same value.  So there is no real semantic benefit to adding `const` here, it is just extra typing.

**But:** some compilers will give a warning...

```
const void *ptr = ...;
string ptr2 = *(string *) ptr;
```

Since you are casting a pointer to `const void` to a pointer to non-const `string`, some compilers may give a warning that you are discarding qualifiers.  C++ compilers shouldn't even let such code pass, since they'll demand a `const_cast` to convert from `const void *` to `string *` (a.k.a `const char *const *`).

**However:** the reverse conversion is fine.  It is fine to pass pointers to non-const objects to `strcmp`.  The fact that `strcmp` takes pointers to const data indicates that `strcmp` itself does not modify the data.

**There are many ways to write the function that are fine.**  Here are some examples.

```
return strcmp(*(char **) p1, *(char **) p2);
return strcmp(*(const char **) p1, *(const char **) p2);
return strcmp(*(char * const *) p1, *(char * const *) p2);
return strcmp(*(const char * const *) p1, *(const char * const *) p2);

// The following are not technically portable, but are portable in practice
return strcmp(*(void **) p1, *(void **) p2);
return strcmp(*(const void **) p1, *(const void **) p2);
return strcmp(*(void * const *) p1, *(void * const *) p2);
return strcmp(*(const void * const *) p1, *(const void * const *) p2);
```

Since you are casting variables anyway, the compiler will let a lot of different potential errors slide, but some compilers *may* give warnings.  Use whichever version suits your coding style.

**Final tip:** The `auto` keyword is obsolete.  It doesn't really mean anything these days -- it's the default storage class specifier.  Don't use `auto`.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough reply. However, there is one thing that I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. You said: "Since you are casting a pointer to const void to a pointer to non-const string, some compilers may give a warning that you are discarding qualifiers." What I'm confused about is that const void *ptr is a void pointer pointing to const data. But (string *) is the same as (const char *), which is a pointer to const data. Why would a compiler complain about this? It sounds as if the void pointer is a const pointer pointing to const data. But that can't be right. So why the cast?

Comment: No, `string *` is not the same as `const char *`, it is the same as `const char **`.  That's why I used the typedef.  If you take a `const void *`, which is a pointer to const, and cast it to `string *`, which is pointer to non-const, then some compilers will complain.

Answer (score 0):

First part of your question, I think there's some flexibility on where you place the `const`, so `const char **` and `char * const *` are the same.

Second part of your question, any pointer can be assigned to a `const` pointer. It's going the other way that generates an error. Your explicit cast removed any knowledge the compiler had about the pointer's original type.

Comment: There is some flexibility, but `const char **` (pointer to pointer to const char) is equivalent only to `char const **`, whereas `char *const *` (pointer to const pointer to char) is different.